# Declare a tool that depends on a parameter to be requested from the user?

Tags: langchain

With langchain chatbot, I have a tool to import a PDF document.
But, I want a tool to ask the user for a URL before being used.

```
class LoadRFP(BaseTool):
    name = "import RFP"
    description = (
        "Useful for when you need to load informations about a PDF"
        ".Input should be the URL of the PDF.")
    return_direct=True

    def _run(self,
             url: HttpUrl,
             run_manager: Optional[CallbackManagerForToolRun] = None,
             ) -> Union[str, List[Document]]:
        return "The document is imported. "
```

How can I configure the chatbot to prompt me for the URL if it doesn't have it, before loading the document?